# Is there any difference between (null != x) and (x != null)

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean-expression

I was watching a java programming video tutorial, and it was mentioning that:

```
if(null != x){
}
```

is it a good practice to use it like above ?

Does it differ from :

```
if(x != null){
}
```

Comment: No difference, I've found `if (x != null)` to be more common.

Comment: @rpattiso me too, that why I am asking, a professor from well known university used the first one

Comment: Some people prefer to put the `null` first, in case of typo to `null = x`. But the comparaison yields the same results.

Comment: @AntonH true but that is a problem in C, not Java right?.

Comment: Lots of C developers tend to use `null !=`, I tend to use the first.  When using `equals` I look for the the mostly not `null` value, for example `"Test String".equals(someStringVariable)`, but that's a different case...

Comment: @rpattiso No, you can do assignments within `if` statements, just like C

Comment: @rpattiso Nah, can happen in Java also. You're just assigning inside the parentheses.

Comment: You may also find it has to do with the way people think "is x not equal to null?" translates to `x != null`...

Comment: In case of `==` `if (null == x)` prevents you from accidentally assigning `null` to `x` in case of typo like `if (x=null)`. But in case of `!=` this mistake can't be done so you are free to chose whichever way you want (but if you start using `null == x` you probably should also use `null != x`).

Comment: @MadProgrammer True, but most of the time it fails to compile because the assignment expression evaluates to a non boolean type. In C this typo always results in valid code.

Comment: @AntonH It can happen, but not likely.  `if (x = null)` would be legal *only* if `x` is a `Boolean` (with an upper-case `B`).  Otherwise either the expression type would not be boolean, or `null` could not be assigned to `x`.

Comment: @rpattiso If `x` is an `Object`, which it would need to be in order to be evaluated to `null` then `if (x = null)` is a valid assignment, `if (null = x)` couldn't work...or am I missing the point?

Comment: @ajb Wouldn't `x` only need to be a `Object` type?  What's the point of trying to evaluate `boolean` to `null`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer The result of the assignment expression matches the variable type, `Boolean x; if(x = null);` is valid but `String x; if (x = null);` is not valid Java because the result of `x = null` is a not a boolean type.

Comment: @rpattiso The assignment is valid, it's the evaluation which is not, `if ((x = null) != null)` will work, but yes, it's a good catch on the side of the compiler ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer If `x` is an `Object`, the type of `x = null` is also an `Object`.  And you can't use an `Object` as the condition of an `if` statement.  We're still talking about Java, right?

Comment: @ajb Yes, but the assignment can work, but not the evaluation.  It could be possible to have a compound condition where an assignment occurs (by accident), followed by an evaluation, allowing the `if` statement to work - but your point is clearer now ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm not sure what kind of compound condition that would be...  Java doesn't allow `x=null && y==null` either.  I think the number of cases where you could replace `==` with `=` in an expression, and both would be legal, is quite small.  I wish it were zero, though.

Comment: @ajb `if ((a = b) != null)` ... yes, it's weird, but it's doable ;) - But your previous comment cleared my confusion, cheers ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I was talking about cases where `=` could be (accidentally) interchanged with `==`, and `if ((a == b) != null)` doesn't seem legal in any case.

Comment: @ajb True that would need to be `!(a==b)`...hmm. None the less, it's cleared the air ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to want to use the second one.

Both do the same exact thing...compare A to B, or compare B to A - both mean the same thing.

It just makes more sense to use `x != null` because that is more like how we would say this.

You could ask me "Is x not null?" That seems more natural than "Is null not x?" It makes more sense to us.

Comment: *You could ask me "Is x not null?" That seems more natural than "Is null not x?"* - that is why `value == variable` is called [yoda condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) :)

Comment: Haha very cool link. Very interesting

Comment: The trouble with the "yoda condition" is that we would be allowed to use `do` in our Java programs but not `try`.....

Comment: sorry, maybe you haven't seen the movie...

Comment: "No. Try not. Do... or do not. There is no try." :) Didn't catch that at first haha nice

Answer (score 2):

I think the most common method used is the latter, but both achieve the same thing.